# updating texture buffer each frame on Android

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I need to update a texture from a byte buffer array each frame.
I know about glTexImage2D but I am afraid it will be to slow.
I have read a bit about textureView and textureSurface which allow to update a texture view dynamically from a camera or a stream (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_textureview.htm), but I didn't find anything on updating a textureSurface from a buffer array.

So any suggestions how I might be able to render dynamic textures on Android from a buffer array with a textureSurface ?

Comment: Is glTexSubImage2D not working for you? It is hard to imagine to have a better performance in sending the data to the GPU then sending a direct chunk of data on an already allocated space...

Comment: ok I finally used glTexSubImage2D, the performance is correct.

Comment: It is correct for real time, it takes few ms to update the texture.